# How to most efficiently use InsertManyAsync()?

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> newRecords)
{
  _mongoDatabaseStorageService.WithRecords<T>(e => e.InsertManyAsync(newRecords).Wait());
}
```

How big can be `newRecords`? I mean how many elements can I set to `InsertManyAsync()` and have the best performance(1000, 10 000, 100 000) any recommendation?